# I`m looking for an rpg that make traps awesome

Tags: game-recommendation, traps

Traps are a staple of rpg, and yet they sour any modern game really fast. Dnd doesnt handle them well with passive perception, and most player dont want to die in a stupid trap after spending an hour or two making their characters.

Where is the fantasy equivalent of paranoia?

What would be perfect is a system where you can generate a character fast and yet compelling enough so you can create a character you like, a setting that give an excuse to introducing new character each time one dies and an hit point system where you can lose limbs, bleed, burn and so on. Im trying to find a reason to use my grimmtooth trap compendium...

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE. I'm sad to inform you that questions like these tend to not be very fitting for the site, both because it's a very broad question, and because it's de facto a game recommendation question (which have been banned some years ago).

Comment: @vicky_molokh see also [Are Game Recommendation Questions On Topic, Revisited](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited)

Comment: @Pierre-LucMarsan Even though game recommendation questions are off-topic on this site, you can have a look at [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go). It's a list of forums (duh), which are well suited to handle these kinds of questions. Good luck, and have a nice day! Hopefully, we'll see you again around here :)

Comment: I`m sorry, i didnt knew it wasnt the place for this question. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.